# Search for results within a region (country, state, large city)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, region, google-geocoding-api

Our website lets people create listings and these include a location field, which is populate by Google's API, just like on Airbnb, for example. You start typing any part of your address and then you select from the Google's suggestions of matching places.

People can search the listings by location (same Google API populated location field, and you can choose what distance from that location), and this seems to work fine in principle.

The issue is that the search doesn't seem to work for areas, e.g. counties. It seems to take a point within the region and measures from that. So, if I  search for listings in "United Kingdom" I get hardly any results 'Within 10 miles' but I get a lot 'Within 250 miles'.

Instead, I want to get all results within the UK if I search for United Kingdom (or a UK county, or within a large city like London).

Why doesn't it work right now, and how can this be done?

Comment: How does your server side code work to determine if each result is in the area that the user has searched?

Comment: Hi Adaam, thanks for your reply. I'm not the guy coding it. The person coding said "the API is working correctly", so I thought I ask here to see whether there might be an answer that would point him into the right direction. I could not find this issue described anywhere so far...

Comment: You need to talk to the guy who is coding it and check about his proximity algorithm. You are presumably sending an AJAX request (upon autocomplete selection) across to a server page with the bounding box coordinates of the viewport. Without more code, i can only speculate.

Comment: Ok. Btw, we're not using a map to display results. IT's just a list. But the results should cover the listings of an entire area, e.g. country or city if that is searched for.

Comment: Okay, post some code, server-side and client please.

Answer (score 4):

To restrict the Autocomplete Box (I guess this is the component you're using) to a country, you can use `componentRestrictions` [as described here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) (scroll to *Restrict the search to a specific country* )

If you need to restrict your search in a specific area, such as "10 miles around a defined point", it's a little more complicated. According to the doc, you'll have to

- Set the bounds on creation of the Autocomplete object.
- Change the bounds on an existing Autocomplete.
- Set the bounds to the map's viewport.
- Restrict the search to a specific country.

You can find an exemple [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) on paragraph *Set the bounds on creation of the Autocomplete object*

Comment: Yes, we're using the autocomplete box, but we don't want to restrict it at all. Users should be able to input any part of an address, worldwide. It's just that when searching for an area, it doesn't really seem to cover the area up to its boundaries, e.g. show all search results within a country.

Comment: I think it does, but it uses a prediction service to guess what the user will search, and I don't know the algorith of this service. Could you provide an example where the behavior of your Autocomplete seems strange ?
Moreover, if you're searching something else than places, like 'pizza' for example, please consider using a `SerachBox` instead of an `Autocomplete`